# ERROR : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Relationship null doesn't start with this part /ppt/slides/slide3.xml

Tags: java, apache-poi, liferay-6, xslf

I'm working with apache poi xslf to export ppt file.
First, I have a template set with 3 slides : title slide, summary slide, and third slide

I duplicate the 3rd slide (i have it as a template) in order to copy many data/graphics as I have in database.

So in order to do that :

```
XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(dlfile.getContentStream());
XSLFSlide[] slides = slideShow.getSlides();
XSLFSlide createdSlide = slideShow.createSlide(slides[2].getSlideLayout());
//get content from slide to createdslide
createdSlide.importContent(slides[2]); 
//... add data to created slide
```

I have an error at line : `createdSlide.importContent(slides[2]);`

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Relationship null doesn't start with this part /ppt/slides/slide3.xml
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.getRelatedPart(PackagePart.java:468)
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.importBlip(XSLFSheet.java:521)
    at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide.importContent(XSLFSlide.java:235)
```

P.S : this code works just fine with another tempalte.
I need to use different templates based on user selection. (templates are stored in db as i'm using liferay).

I've searched for hours, but in vain!
I don't even understand what the error means.

Any links/help would appreciated.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I'm getting poi.jar with dependency through liferay. I don't know wich version i'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from [org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.getRelatedPart](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackagePart.java#PackagePart.getRelatedPart%28org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationship%29) code line 468:

`throw new IllegalArgumentException("Relationship " + rel + " doesn't start with this part " + _partName);`.

The error states that `rel` is null. So [org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.importBlip](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSheet.java#XSLFSheet.importBlip%28java.lang.String%2Corg.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart%29) in code line 521:

`blipPart = packagePart.getRelatedPart(blipRel);`

had handed over `blipRel`as null. So [org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide.importContent](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlide.java#XSLFSlide.importContent%28org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet%29) in code line 235:

`String relId = importBlip(blipId, src.getPackagePart());`

had handed over `blipId` as null.

This is pretty clear if one of the pictures in your template in Slide 3 is not an embedded picture but a linked picture. The code:

```
@Override
public XSLFSlide importContent(XSLFSheet src){
    super.importContent(src);

    XSLFBackground bgShape = getBackground();
    if(bgShape != null) {
        CTBackground bg = (CTBackground)bgShape.getXmlObject();
        if(bg.isSetBgPr() && bg.getBgPr().isSetBlipFill()){
            CTBlip blip = bg.getBgPr().getBlipFill().getBlip();
            String blipId = blip.getEmbed();

            String relId = importBlip(blipId, src.getPackagePart());
            blip.setEmbed(relId);
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

consideres only embedded blip data.

From your code lines I can see that you are using `apache poi` version 3.9. But as far as I see in current versions this had not changed until now. Only embedded bilp data will be considered.

So have a look at your template and make sure that all pictures are embedded and not linked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Indeed, it was from the picture in my template. As a newbie i couldn't understand what it was about :)